# Using strtok to separate words and remove , and ()

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

My program is supposed to take a phrase and separate all words and print them on a new line without any ',', '(' or ')'. This is my code. So far it seems to be working but I would like to improve it if possible. Also, I don't know if it's a problem or not, but it seems to remove '(' and ')' from a single word but not both. So "(test" or "test)" will output only "test", as intended, but "(test)" outputs "test)". Not sure if that's ok or not..anyhow how could I improve that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *string)
{
    const char delim[2] = " ";
    char *token;
    int n, i, j;

    token = strtok(string, delim);
    while (token != NULL) {
        n = strlen(token);
        if (strstr(token, ",")) {
            for (i = j = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (token[i] != ',')
                    token[j++] = token[i];
            }
            token[j] = '\0';
        }else if (strstr(token, "(")) {
            for (i = j = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (token[i] != '(')
                    token[j++] = token[i];
            }
            token[j] = '\0';
        } else if (strstr(token, ")")) {
            for (i = j = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (token[i] != ')')
                    token[j++] = token[i];
            }
            token[j] = '\0';
        }

        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char test[80] = "The next appointment is on the 7.1.2019, 10:00 a.m., in HS 1 (Building C)";
    char input[80];

    gets(input);
    function(test);
    function(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only check for `)` if there was no `(` found. That does not make any sense. you should check for each of the characters and as long as you find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can do just like the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *string)
{
    const char delim[10] = " ,()";
    char *token = strtok(string, delim);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char test[80] = "The next appointment is on the 7.1.2019, 10:00 a.m., in HS 1 (Building C)";

    function(test);

    return 0;
}
```

Explain:

> Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string
>          containing the next token.  This string does not include the
>          delimiting byte.  If no more tokens are found, strtok() returns NULL.

see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

Comment: could you please explain how delim is used ? so it's function is to remove every symbol and then the result is token ?

Comment: @saty, as Yunbin says, read the man page for a detailed description

Comment: @Saty yes, `strtok()` remove all char in `delim`